# Single row with only values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get a single row with only the values, I don't want to see the NULL values.  I know I can make a Temp table from this query and then select MAX on the Temp table, but was wondering if there is a way to do it within this query.

```
Select VisitIDCode
,CASE WHEN (LeftJustifiedLabel) = 'Additional Intervention Information' Then (ValueText) Else Null End As 'Additional Intervention Information'
,CASE WHEN (LeftJustifiedLabel) = 'American Cancer Society Comment:' Then (ValueText) Else Null End As 'American Cancer Society Comment:'
,CASE WHEN (LeftJustifiedLabel) = 'Intevention' Then (ValueText) Else Null End As 'Intevention'
From #AssessmentFS
WHERE VisitIDCode = 123
```

Here is my current end result from the query above, I only added one Case field because it's to long for the others.

```
VisitIDCode  Additional Intervention Information  
123          Faxed referral to 877-428-2862
123          NULL
123          NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate (use `max` or `min` etc) in the same query.

```
select 
VisitIDCode
,MAX(CASE WHEN LeftJustifiedLabel = 'Additional Intervention Information' Then ValueText End) As 'Additional Intervention Information'
,MAX(CASE WHEN LeftJustifiedLabel = 'American Cancer Society Comment:' Then ValueText End) As 'American Cancer Society Comment:'
,MAX(CASE WHEN LeftJustifiedLabel = 'Intevention' Then ValueText End) As 'Intevention'
From #AssessmentFS
group by VisitIDCode
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going to go in that direction but then second guessed myself.

Comment: @user3666224 [Feel free to accept this answer if you feel it was useful to you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)